# selecting/highlighting a column only from a table 'like github does it'?

Tags: javascript, css, html

The source code in github is stored in a html table like this:

```
<table><tbody>
<tr><td>1</td><td>// here is a comment</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>var i = 1;</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>console.log(i);</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

How can I select/highlight this table so that I don't select the line numbers ?
In other words: How can I select only a portion of a second column ?

*I know github does it but I can't work out how*

*possibly without jquery*

Comment: Based on what you added as a comment to my answer, you might want to clarify that you are not talking about highlighting, but **selection** and you don't want the numbers to be selectable ...

Comment: @rfornal will do that... thanks (I thought it was obvious from the title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they have done is something like this ...

```
<table><tbody>
<tr>
  <td class='line-number'>1</td>
  <td class='line-code'>// here is a comment</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class='line-number'>2</td>
  <td class='line-code'>var i = 1;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class='line-number'>3</td>
  <td class='line-code'>console.log(i);</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Then, all they do is change the background and/or foreground for the class `line-code`.

```
.line-code {
  background-color: silver;
  color: white;
}
```

To keep the numbers from being selected, try this ...

```
.line-number {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

This will block the content from being selected, therefore allowing a clean copy.

Comment: that can't be true otherwise when I'd paste the highlighted code I would paste the linenumbers too

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't want to use classes you could always use something like this.

```css
tr td+td {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<table><tbody>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>// here is a comment</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>var i = 1;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>console.log(i);</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `user-select: none` style to disable user selection. You should add its vendor-prefixed equivalents to make the CSS cross browser compatible.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table tr td {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

table tr > td:first-child {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #eee;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>1</td><td>// here is a comment</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>var i = 1;</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>console.log(i);</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution

html:

```
<table><tbody>
<tr><td>1</td><td>// here is a comment</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>var i = 1;</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>console.log(i);</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>console.log(i);</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td><td>console.log(i);</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td><td>console.log(i);</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td><td>console.log(i);</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td><td>console.log(i);</td></tr>
  <tr><td>9</td><td>console.log(i);</td></tr>
  <tr><td>10</td><td>console.log(i);</td></tr>
  <tr><td>11</td><td>console.log(i);</td></tr>
  <tr><td>12</td><td>console.log(i);</td></tr>
  <tr><td>13</td><td>console.log(i);</td></tr>
  <tr><td>14</td><td>console.log(i);</td></tr>
  <tr><td>15</td><td>console.log(i);</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

css:

```
body{
  color:black;
}

table{
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width:80%;
}

td:nth-child(1){
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 5%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

td:nth-child(1):hover{
  color:white;
  background-color: black;
}

td:nth-child(2){
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 95%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.highlight td:nth-child(1){
  color:white;
  background-color: black;
}

.highlight td:nth-child(2){
  background-color: #BFDA18;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr td:nth-child(1)').click(function(){
    $('tr.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).parent().addClass('highlight');
  });
});
```

codepen link:   http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jELOwY

Comment: I don't get it. I just went to your codepen and when I highlight a couple of lines of code I also highlight the linenumbers. I am using chrome

Comment: when you click on line number, the line gets highlighted. Isn't that what you want? Or perhaps you are hoping for an exact replica of github?

Comment: I have just editted the codepen example. I guess this is what you are looking for

Comment: @Ji_in_coding He wants to highlight/select the codes for copy/pasting but not selecting the line numbers. Not highlight as in change its color